# Fail2Ban does not send emails

Tags: centos, fail2ban

**Dear friends,**

Once again, I would like to enlist the help of this group!

My fail2ban does not send emails in any way. I would like blocking notifications to be sent via email, but I can't seem to get this to work.

**This is my jail.conf:**
https://temporario.aprendendolinux.com/fail2ban/jail.conf.txt

**And this is my jail.local:**
[https://temporario.aprendendolinux.com/fail2ban/jail.local.txt](https://temporario.aprendendolinux.com/fail2ban/jail.conf.txt)

**And this is my fail2ban.conf:**
[https://temporario.aprendendolinux.com/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf.txt](https://temporario.aprendendolinux.com/fail2ban/jail.conf.txt)

**Environment details:**
CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)
Fail2ban 0.10.5-2

Where can I go wrong?
I made sure that the server is capable of sending emails, with the command below:

`echo 'Testing email service!' | mutt -s 'Testing sending emails!' - magnatahp@gmail.com`

And the email arrives correctly.

Can someone help me? I'll be very grateful.

Ps: Sorry for any typos. I'm brazilian. I'm not very good with English!

Sincerely,

[Henrique Fagundes](https://www.aprendendolinux.com)

Answer (score 2):

You have `action = %(action_)s` in your `jail.local`. Change it to `action = %(action_mw)s` or add this line to each service you want to get notifications.